# What is the Time Complexity of finding all possible ways from one to another?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, vertex

Here I use a pseudocode to present my algorithm,it's a variation of **DFS**
The coding style is imitating the  **Introduction to Algorithm** ,Everytime we come across a vertex,its color is painted **BLACK** .Suppose the starting vertex is **START**,and the target vertex is **TARGET**,and the graph is represented as **G=(V,E)**.One more thing,assume that the graph is connected,and strongly connected if it's a directed graph.

```
FIND-ALL-PATH(G,START,END)
  for each vertex u in G.V
         u.color=WHITE
  path=0//store the result
         DFS-VISIT(G,START)



DFS-VISIT(G,u)
    if(u==TARGET)
       path=path+1
       return
    u.color=BLACK  
    for each v in G:Adj[u]
       if(v.color==WHITE)
           DFS-VISIT(G,v)
    u.color=WHITE;//re-paint the vertex to find other possible ways
```

How to analyze the **Time Complexity** of the algorithm above?If it's the normal DFS then of course its O(N+E),because each vertex is visited only once,and each edge is visited twice.But what about this?It seems hard to specify the time that each vertex or edge is visited.

Answer (score 2):

To analyze the time complexity for `FIND-ALL-PATH`, let's see what is the time complexity of `DFS-VISIT`. I am assuming you are using Adjacency List for representing the Graph.

Here, in one call of `DFS-VISIT` every vertex which is connected to `u` (the vertex you passed as the argument) is going to be explored once (i.e. vertex color is going to be changed to BLACK). Since this is a recursive function so in each recursion a new stack is going to be formed and there the set `G:Adj[u]` present in each stack is nothing but element adjacent to `u`. Therefore, every node in all the list put together will be examined(color is changed) exactly once and whenever they are examined, we do a constant work (i.e. O(1) operation). There are overall E elements in case of directed Graph and 2E in case of un-directed Graph in Adjacency List representation. So we say it's time is O(E), where `E` is the number of edges. In some books, they add extra time O(N), where `N` is the number of vertices, so they say they overall time complexity for `DFS-VISIT` is O(N+E)(I think that the reason for that extra O(N) time is the for loop which gets executed `N` number of times or it may be something else). BTW, `N` is always less than `E` so you can either ignore it or consider it, it doesn't affect the Asymptotic time for the `DFS-VISIT`.

The time complexity of the function `FIND-ALL-PATH` is **N * time complexity for DFS-VISIT**; where `N` is the number of vertices in the Graph. So I would say that the algorithm you wrote above is not exactly same as depth-first traversal algorithm but then it will do the same work as depth-first traversal. The time taken in your algorithms is more because you are calling `DFS-VISIT` for each vertex in your graph. Your function `FIND-ALL-PATH` could be optimized in a way that before calling `DFS-VISIT` function just check if the color of the vertex is changed to `BLACK` or not (that's what is generally done in depth-first traversal).
i.e. you should have written the function like this:

```
FIND-ALL-PATH(G,START,END)
  for each vertex u in G.V
         u.color=WHITE
  path=0//store the result
  for each vertex u in G.V
         if u.color is WHITE
                 DFS-VISIT(G,START)
```

Now this function written above will have same time complexity as `DFS-VISIT`.

Also note that there is some time taken to initialize the color of all vertices to WHITE, which is O(N) operation.

So, the overall time complexity of your function `FIND-ALL-PATH` is **O(N)+O(N*(N+E))** or you can ignore the first O(N) (as it's very less as compared to the other term).

Thus, time complexity = **O(N*(N+E))**, or if you assume just O(E) time for your `DFS-VISIT` function then you can say that time complexity is **O(N*E)**.

Let me know if you have doubt at any point mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry,I've made a mistake,I should not call the `DFS-VISIT()` for each vertex.Instead I should just call the DFS-VISIT(G,START) once,and I've modified the question.Thank you  for your detailed answer.

Comment: But still  one question,in your answer you said "every node in all the list put together will be examined(color is changed) exactly once".This make sense in the normal DFS,but here I've made a little change——the color of each node is re-printed to WHITE(See the last line of code),after all the path passing this node is explored.That is to say,if we take the node TARGET as an example,the node TARGET will be explored N times,which equals to the count of paths starting from START to TARGET

Comment: What's more,I think the time complexity of `DFS-VISIT` here is not **O(V+E)**. We all know that **dijkstra** has **O(V^2+E)**.So if the `DFS-VISIT` is **O(V+E)**,we can just modify it and get a better algorithm to find the shortest path from START to TARGET,since `DFS-VISIT` could find all the paths from START to TARGET.

Answer (score 0):

**For directed graph :-**

Suppose there are 7 vertices {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} and consider the worst case where every vertex is connected to every other vertex =>

No of edges required to reach from x to y vertices is as follows :

(6->6) 6 to 6 =0

(5->6) 5 to 6 =1

(4->6) 4 to 6 = (4 to 5 -> 6) + (4 to 6->6)  = (1+( 5 -> 6)) + (1+0) =(1 + 1) + 1= 3

(3->6) 3 to 6 =(3 to 4 -> 6) + (3 to 5 -> 6 ) + (3 to 6->6)  = (1+3) + (1+1) + (1+0)=7

(2->6) 2 to 6= 4+7+3+1=15

(1->6) 1 to 6= 5+15+7+3+1=31

(0->6) 0 to 6 = 6+5+15+7+3+1=63

So the time complexity to cover all the path to reach from 0 to 6= summation of (1+3+7+15+.....+T(n-1)+T(n))+(Total no of vertices -1) = (2^(n+1)-2-n)+(V-1)

value of n=V-1.

So final time complexity = O(2^V)

**For undirected graph :-**

Every edge will be traversed twice = 2*((2^(n+1)-2-n)+(V-1))=O(2^(V+1))